# Zip file works well but still getting an error System.IO.InvalidDataException: 'End of Central Directory record could not be found.'

Tags: c#, .net, system.io.compression

I am using the ZipFile method in the System.IO.Compression library. Here is the simple function I have written :

```
public void zipUnzip()
        {
            string zipPath = @"C:\zipped_folder.zip";
            string extractPath = @"C:\extract";
            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath, true);
        }
```

I am able to unzip the file manually, in windows explorer but when I execute the above function I get the error :

```
System.IO.InvalidDataException: 'End of Central Directory record could not be found.'
```

Not quite sure how to troubleshoot this now. Can someone please help?